# Helicopter Game Terrain for XNA

Tags: xna

So i am trying to make this game in XNA http://www.addictinggames.com/helicopter.html. So far everything is going ok. My only question is how to create the jagged edges. What idea/method is behind it. Do i deform the top and the bottom or is there a Fake/smarter way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: You might want to post on the game development site...

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method? just render a bunch of squares with different transformations to get the different sizes. or a simpler method, just render flat polygons. You can easily use something like [triangulator](http://triangulator.codeplex.com/) to easily generate the vertices and indices if you don't want to do it yourself.